# Do you have to pay cleaner costs even when the mission is aborted?

Tags: payday-2

Per the question [Who pays the cleaner?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131642/who-pays-the-cleaner) we know money for killing civilians comes directly out of your spendable money.

But do you still have to pay the cleanup crew if you quit the mission (disconnecting from server, suicide by cop/gravity, time machine, etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's find out. For ***SCIENCE!***

To do this, I noted my initial cash:

[image: Cash: $7,193,630]

Then, I killed 3 civilians, each with a cleaner cost of $3,000, and quit the mission.

Here is my final balance after that:

[image: Cash: $7,184,630]

In conclusion, cleaner costs are deducted at the time of civilian death, not at the time of mission end. Therefore, it is **not** a good idea to kill all the civilians after a failure, unless you have money to burn.

Comment: An interesting side-effect of this experiment found that civilians do, in fact, set off trip mines.

...don't ask.

Comment: Deleted my answer, thanks for clearing that up in a better way.

Comment: Jeah for science :D

Comment: Hell, that's good to know !

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Nothing is more satisfying than some good, old-fashioned, bold-italics science.