# What happens when you kill a civilian when you have no money?

Tags: payday-2

I'm wondering what happens if you have $0 in your spending money and you shoot and kill a civilian?

Comment: If I had to guess, the cleaner just doesn't get paid or the money pools up and is deducted when you have enough.

Comment: @TimmyJim If you had to guess, you'd guess you either don't pay for it or you do? Seems a fairly safe bet! :P

Comment: You don't pay is what I was saying. Or, when you have enough money, you do pay.  Seems like you don't pay though looking at the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you have $0 spending money at the time you kill a civilian, no money is technically deducted. [Cleaner costs are deducted directly from your spending money as soon as you kill a civilian](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132405/do-you-have-to-pay-cleaner-costs-even-when-the-mission-is-aborted/132449#132449), and your spending money cannot go into the negative. Therefore, no money is actually deducted from your spending money.